# Magnific Popup - Delay popup for 100 seconds & make close work like checkmark

Tags: popup, magnific-popup

I am not a javscript coder so I need some help on this.

1. I would like the popup to load after 100 seconds.
2. I would like that if the user clicks on the close X that the popup closes for 30 days for that user...much like the click in dismissal does now.

If you can help me out with this I would be very happy :).

Here is the code I am using for my Magnific Popup:

```
var et_popup_closed = $.cookie('etheme_popup_closed');
$('.etheme-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    preloader: false,
    focus: '#username',
    modal: true
});

if(et_popup_closed != 'do-not-show') {
    $('.etheme-popup').click();
}

$(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();
    if($('#showagain:checked').val() == 'do-not-show')
        $.cookie('etheme_popup_closed', 'do-not-show', { expires: 30, path: '/' } );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

to initialize the popup with delay, use setTimeout

```
    $(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
     items: {
            src: '#ID' //ID OF INLINE ELEMENT
                },
            type:'inline',
      mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
            });
     }, 100000);  // equals 100 seconds
        });
```

you can change the type:'inline' part by anything (like type:'image') and change the src

you can view a [demo here](http://www.hoopsvilla.com/2014/02/nba-2k15-wishlist-your-opinion-official.html)  (opens after 18 seconds after window load)

for the cookie part, i have been been trying to figure it out too..